# Is there a solution to $(c+x)f'(c+x)=c(x-f(x))$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

(possibly under the condition f(0)=0).

In general, is there a name for differential equations which feature the function f evaluated at another function of the argument, e.g. something like f(g(x))=f'(x) for some known function g(x)?

Thank you!

Comment: I think what you're looking for is called a [delay differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation).